# How to get the 2D postition of an Object in front of a camera

Tags: c#, 3d, camera, projection

How can i project the (known) 3D position of a photographed person, to his 2D position in the taken picture? Both 3D positions, of the camera and the person in front of it, are known.

Comment: Are you asking about how to do a [perspective projection?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection)

Comment: after reading a little bit about the topic, i think thats what i need, but i am looking for a way without doing the math myself.

Comment: Are you using a 3D graphics library/framework/engine for your project? Most of them have built in methods for lots of different linear algebra like projections. If you're not, you're going to have to roll your own, which without knowing how to do it mathematically, will be a real PITA.

Comment: It will depend on the projection (camera) you're using. Orthographic or perspective.. orthographic is quite immediate, perspective requires a little bit of maths.